# Access Denied Error in Admin Panel Custom Moduel

Tags: module, custom, acl, access

I am getting access denied error for 3 Tabs in admin panel.

Custom module config is under

```
<acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <vendor>
                        <title>Vendor</title>
                        <children>                                
                            <orders>
                                <title>Orders</title>
                            </orders>
                            <transaction>
                                <title>Transactions</title>
                            </transaction>
                            <review>
                                <title>Reviews</title>
                            </review>
                        </children>
                    </vendor>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <cartmart>
                                        <title>Cart Mart Section</title>
                                    </cartmart>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

Comment: Please also show the `<menu>` element of your configuration and the relevant controller code. Also are you getting "Access denied" for a role with full access or with these permissions explicitly set?

Answer (score 0):

Log out and log back in. If you just installed the module and have not yet logged out, this is expected behavior.

Comment: I tried it. I'm logged into VENDOR role

Comment: Have you also cleared the cache?